# "i" tag in "p" goes into text and not affected by margin

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome, absolute

[image: a screenshot]

Above, the left icon is not affected by my `p` tag but the right one is.

```css
p {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #505050;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  i:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  i:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<p>
    <span>%%%</span>
    <span>%%%</span>
    <span>%%%</span>
    <span>
         <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-1x" aria-hidden="true "></i>
         Fondateur du studio
         <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: So what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: The left icon should be shifted by 1em by the right and the top

Comment: The right and the top of what ? Please be relentlessly precise about the behavior you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
p {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #505050;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

i:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1em;
}

i:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p>
  <span>
      <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum mollitia blanditiis voluptatum consequuntur in harum! Porro, sequi! Molestiae iure nam maiores eveniet veniam ipsum fuga voluptatibus cum eligendi, odio sint.
      <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Always add a qualifying explanation